# Change default groups assigned to new users

Tags: permissions

When a new user is created, they are assigned to a set of default groups. How do I change which default groups are assigned?

Answer (score 2):

That can change according to the way you are creating the new user.

If you are using `useradd` you can either specify the `-G` option or use that dirty (very dirty) workaround : rewriting a useradd script.

There is maybe a possibility to specify multiple default groups in /etc/default/useradd but I could not find anything in the man or online in the couple of minutes of research I did. So if you really need to do it you can :

```
mv /usr/bin/useradd /usr/bin/useradd.default
```

and now recreate /usr/bin/useradd with the following content

```
#!/bin/bash 

useradd.default -G somegroup,otheradditionnalgroup "$@"
```

Now make this executable
    chmod +x /usr/bin/useradd

And you should be ready to go.

It may happen that the useradd command is not located in /usr/bin . You can find it using `whereis useradd`

Once again, this is a dirty hack that will be overwritten by an update. Be careful when doing something like this.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using the `adduser` command to add new users:

Open /etc/adduser.conf in your text editor of choice and scroll down until you see #EXTRA_GROUPS.

Uncomment this and the #ADD_EXTRA_GROUPS line beneath it.

Set the value of EXTRA_GROUPS to whatever you would like the groups to be for new users aside from their own named group.

Save and start creating new users.