# Where does Ubuntu store the default groups new users are added to?

Tags: users, groups

Is there a file that contains the list of default groups that all newly created users will belong to?

An answer to the following question provides a work-around for creating users with certain group membership, but doesn't answer whether or not a list of default groups is stored somewhere?

[Change default groups assigned to new users](https://askubuntu.com/questions/507685/change-default-groups-assigned-to-new-users)

It's hard to believe that this is hard-coded directly into the `/usr/bin/useradd` binary.

Comment: Have you consulted `man useradd`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default any new user created with `adduser` (or from the GUI) will be in this user's group only. There is no list of additional groups.

We can add additional groups we wish a new use should be in in the configuration file `/etc/adduser.conf`. Just uncomment the line to define the variable `EXTRA_GROUPS` and add groups you need there.

```
# This is the list of groups that new non-system users will be added to
# Default:
#EXTRA_GROUPS="dialout cdrom floppy audio video plugdev users"
```